# Can anyone explaine this command line?

Tags: arm, u-boot

```
System.map: u-boot
            @$(NM) $< | \
            grep -v '\(compiled\)\|\(\.o$$\)\|\( [aUw] \)\|\(\.\.ng$$\)\|\(LASH[RL]DI\' | \
            sort > System.map
```

This is the command lines in Makefile of u-boot to generate System.map. I just hope to understand how this command works to associate physical address with instructions. I didn't see any calculation.

Answer (score 0):

The calculations are done by the [`nm`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nm) program that is called on the first line. The rest is just filtering the output. You can use `nm` to do whatever work you need. It's implementation is dependent on the format of the file, so there's no single answer to how to write it yourself, but there are opensource implementations (look in the linux source for instance).